# How to add transformation of white lines on a picture in python/pytorch?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to add faint white diagonal lines (similar to [these lines](https://www.thebest3d.com/dogwaffle/help/PDHelp/video_14.jpg) except that they're diagonal) into images for a machine learning task. Does anyone know whether these transformations have a name and how I can replicate them on images (in python/pytorch preferably)?

Comment: Diagonal ? What ?

Comment: Add a sinusoidal function of y (possibly to some power).

Comment: Ah didn't think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fragment of code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_lines(image, line_width = 5, line_intensity = 0.8, row_effect = 0.45):
    s_shape = (image.height, image.width)
    
    if row_effect == "aspect":
        row_effect = image.width/image.height
    
    lines = Image.fromarray(np.full(s_shape, 255, dtype=np.uint8), "L").convert("RGBA")
    alpha = np.zeros(s_shape)
    line_fun = lambda x : int(line_intensity*255/2*(np.sin(2*np.pi/line_width*x)+1))
    for col_index in range(alpha.shape[1]):
        for row_index in range(alpha.shape[0]):
            alpha[row_index, col_index] = line_fun(col_index + row_effect*row_index)
    alpha = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(alpha), "L")
    new_image = image.copy().convert("RGBA")
    new_image.paste(lines, (0,0), alpha)
    return new_image

source = Image.open("source.jpg")
source_lines = add_lines(source, line_width=5, line_intensity=0.4, row_effect="aspect")
_, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axs[0].imshow(source)
axs[1].imshow(source_lines)
```

The most important is of course the `add_lines` function.
To solve Your problem we proceed as follows:

- Create a fully white grayscale image with the shape of the source image,
- create an array of the same size as the source, but with all zeros,
- define a sine function, rescaled so it is in range [0, line_intensity*255], and with period of line_width,
- for each column in the alpha array fill it with the value of the sine function with the column index as a parameter, and some percentage of the row index as well, this percentage defines how much "diagonal" will the lines be. If You need a 45 degree angle of the lines, just set row_effect to 1, and if You need it to go exactly diagonally through the image, set it to the aspect ratio of the image.
- convert both the source and the `lines` to RGBA, and the alpha mask to grayscale,
- paste the `lines` image to the `source`, using alpha as the mask.

This relatively simple code produces the following result:
[image: Code result]